# Error when trying to open my .java file (File not found: )

Tags: java

I was working on a project and when I finished I compiled it and Eclipse saved it automatically, when I tried to compress the project I found out there was nothing in the src folder, in both the rar and the normal file. Then I tried opening it in Eclipse and the error on the screenshot showed up.

[image]

Comment: So you know, I have downvoted partly for the request for urgency, and partly because you've not explained how you came by this error. Under no circumstances should questions here ask for faster treatment than other questions - in any case it creates work for editors, since it needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like you opened a rar archive by doubleclicking and then opened file in it. This would then be temporary and windows might delete if rar process finished. Unpack that .rar to non-temp location and adjust your path.